# How to install MySQL Workbench?

Tags: applications, release-jolnir

How to install MySQL Workbench?

I go here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Then I select and download version for Ubuntu Linux

When I try to install there is error: Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>=2.28.2)

Can't find a way to install libatkmm 2.28.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to Archives for the download. The current version of MySQL Workbench supports only Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10, and the current version of eleventyOS is based on Ubuntu 20.04.
In archives, you need to select the latest version of MySQL Workbench that supports Ubuntu 20.04 - 8.0.29

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem!